# Geometry question on circles

Tags: geometry

Consider in the plane a circle with center O and a line l not intersecting circle. How do I prove that there is a unique point Q on the perpendicular drawn from O to the line l,such that for any point P on the line l, PQ represents the length of the tangent from P to the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Use coordinates. Let the $y$ axis be the perpendicular from $O$ to $l$, so that $O$ has a positive $y$.

Let the $x$ axis be $l$. Let $P(a,0)$, $O(0,h)$, $Q(0,t)$, and the radius of the circle be $r$.

The length of the tangent from $P$ to the circle is $\sqrt{PO^2-r^2}=\sqrt{a^2+h^2-r^2}$.

The length of $PQ$ is $\sqrt{a^2+t^2}$.

For the two values to be the same, we must have $h^2-r^2=t^2$.

This clearly has a single value of $t$, since $t \ge 0$ (if not this problem needs to be fixed), and $h > r$ from the condition that the circle does not touch the line.

The only point satisfying the condition is $(0,\sqrt{h^2-r^2})$. We are done. $\blacksquare$